How to convert python https requests using requests_pkcs12 to nodejs axios?
I have the python code bellow that makes a https request using the lib requests_pkcs12
import base64
import json
from requests_pkcs12 import post

url = "https://example.com/authenticate"
certificate = 'certificate.pfx'
password = 'xxxxxx'

consumer = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

headers = {
  "Authorization": "Basic " + consumer,
  "role-type": "third",
  "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
body = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}

response = post(url,
  data=body,
  headers=headers,
  verify=True,
  pkcs12_filename=certificate,
  pkcs12_password=password)

print(response.content.decode("utf-8"))

I am trying to convert this code above to node.js using the axios lib:
const axios = require("axios");
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");

const consumer = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
const url      = "https://example.com/authenticate";

const data = {
  grant_type: "client_credentials",
};

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  pfx: fs.readFileSync("./certificate.pfx"),
  passphrase: "xxxxxx"
});

axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']   = "Basic " + consumer;
axios.defaults.headers.common['Role-Type']       = "Third";
axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type']    = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

var results = axios.post(url, {
  data: data,
  httpsAgent: httpsAgent
})
.then((res) => console.log(res.data))
.catch((err) => console.log(err));

But I am receiving the error message: certificate not found.
It seens that the way that I am inserting the certificate into the axios request is not the same way that the python lib requests_pkcs12 uses. How to do this?
